# Opentok Switch to back camera SessionDispatcher:error

Tags: opentok, tokbox

When I try to switch the video to the back camera I receive the following error(s):

```
OpenTok:SessionDispatcher:error A stream does not exist with the id of 58b71fe2-87ef-4e7f-b087-e230af1b1692, for stream#deleted message! +0ms

OpenTok:Publisher:error onStreamAvailableError OT_CONSTRAINTS_NOT_SATISFIED: It's not possible to satisfy one or more constraints passed into the getUserMedia function (getUserMedia error: OverconstrainedError) +0ms

OpenTok:GlobalExceptionHandler:error OT.exception :: title: Unable to Publish (1500) msg: GetUserMedia +0ms

Unhandled Promise Rejection: OT_CONSTRAINTS_NOT_SATISFIED: It's not possible to satisfy one or more constraints passed into the getUserMedia function (getUserMedia error: OverconstrainedError)
```

This error is not consistent, sometimes the camera switch does work. Does anyone know what this error means? Thanks in advance.

Comment: TokBox Developer Evangelist here. Could you please share which version of the OpenTok JS SDK you're using along with the browser version?

Comment: Hi Manik, OpenTok is on v4.3.0 and browser is Safari 12 on an iPhone.

Comment: Hmm, our latest release for OpenTok.js is on 2.15.5 - could you please check the version number in your package.json file or check the CDN link if you're pointing to that.

Comment: I am using this SDK https://github.com/opentok/OpenTok-PHP-SDK